# Delete occurrences of an element if it occurs more than n times in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

How can I fix my code to pass the test case for [Delete occurrences of an element if it occurs more than n times](https://www.codewars.com/kata/delete-occurrences-of-an-element-if-it-occurs-more-than-n-times/python)?

My current code pass one test case and I'm sure that the problem is caused by `order.remove(check_list[i])`.

However, there is no way to delete the specific element with `pop()` because it is required to put an index number rather than the element in `pop()`.

**Test case**

```
Test.assert_equals(delete_nth([20,37,20,21], 1), [20,37,21])
Test.assert_equals(delete_nth([1,1,3,3,7,2,2,2,2], 3), [1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2])
```

**Program**

```py
def delete_nth(order, max_e):
    # code here
    check_list = [x for x in dict.fromkeys(order) if order.count(x) > 1]
    print(check_list)
    print(order)

    for i in range(len(check_list)):
       while(order.count(check_list[i]) > max_e):
           order.remove(check_list[i])
           #order.pop(index)


    return order
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include a description of the problem you're solving; not as an external link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertions fails, because the order is not preserved. Here is a simple example of how this could be done without doing redundant internal loops to count the occurrences for each number:

```
def delete_nth(order, max_e):
    # Get a new list that we will return
    result = []

    # Get a dictionary to count the occurences
    occurrences = {}

    # Loop through all provided numbers
    for n in order:

        # Get the count of the current number, or assign it to 0
        count = occurrences.setdefault(n, 0)

        # If we reached the max occurence for that number, skip it
        if count >= max_e:
            continue

        # Add the current number to the list
        result.append(n)

        # Increase the 
        occurrences[n] += 1

    # We are done, return the list
    return result

assert delete_nth([20,37,20,21], 1) == [20, 37, 21]
assert delete_nth([1, 1, 1, 1], 2) == [1, 1]
assert delete_nth([1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2], 3) == [1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2]
assert delete_nth([1, 1, 2, 2], 1) == [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

A version which maintains the order:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def delete_nth(order, max_e):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    delet = []
    for i, v in enumerate(order):
        count[v] += 1
        if  count[v] > max_e:
            delet.append(i)
    for i in reversed(delet): # start deleting from the end
        order.pop(i)
    return order

print(delete_nth([1,1,2,2], 1))
print(delete_nth([20,37,20,21], 1))
print(delete_nth([1,1,3,3,7,2,2,2,2], 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np

def delete_nth(order, max_e):
    if(len(order)<=max_e):
        return order
    elif(max_e<=0):
        return []
    return np.array(
          sorted(
              np.concatenate(
                [list(v)[:max_e] 
                    for k,v in groupby(
                       sorted(
                          zip(order, list(range(len(order)))), 
                       key=lambda k: k[0]), 
                    key=lambda k: k[0])
                ]
              ), 
           key=lambda k: k[1])
         )[:,0].tolist()
```

Outputs:

```py
print(delete_nth([2,3,4,5,3,2,3,2,1], 2))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1]

print(delete_nth([2,3,4,5,5,3,2,3,2,1], 1))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]

print(delete_nth([2,3,4,5,3,2,3,2,1], 3))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1]

print(delete_nth([2,2,1,1], 1))
[2, 1]
```

Comment: Ok, readability- I can give it to you- it's not that trivial to make it readable tbh - I will try though. What about 2 tweaks - what do you mean?

Comment: First error is `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. After appending `.tolist()`, the next error is `ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider some of the edge cases! Good spot.

Comment: Not much spotting, I mainly just tried submitting it :-). Still needs that `.tolist()` but then it passes the tests.

Answer (score -1):

Originally my answer only worked for one test case, this is quick (not the prettiest) but works for both:

```
def delete_nth(x, e):
    x = x[::-1]
    for i in x:
        while x.count(i) > e:
            x.remove(i)
    return x[::-1]
```

Comment: What do you  mean with "quick"?